# Scratches in light marble vanity top

Tags: countertops, marble, scratches

We have a vanity with a light marble top with under counter sink. Nail polish or something was spilled on it and my wife scraped it off with some sort of knife. The nail polish was removed but it left some little thin scratches in the marble. Is there a way to "polish" or in other ways remove the scratches? They are very small but visible when you look at that part of the top.

Comment: Doesn't help you now - but you might suggest for future reference that "nail polish remover" will probably remove nail polish from more surfaces than just nails ...

Comment: Can see this link for removing scratches.  For the fine sandpaper I would use 400 or 600 grit.  https://marble.com/articles/how-to-remove-scratches-from-marble#

Answer (score 1):

Very likely the top is polyester ( often called "epoxy") with marble filler, especially because acetone had any affect on it. It should polish well; try auto rubbing compound and then polishing compound for more polish. I think the biggest concern is that you do not remove much material and leave a low spot to collect water. That is why sand paper (silicon carbide) like 400 or 600 grit should be used with caution as they can remove material . Also the same reason a power buffer /sander should be used with caution.